# How to avoid error on server side when running client side because of componentDidMount()

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, request, fetch

I have a small node, express react app. Server-side is running on port 5000 and Client-side is running on port 3000. When the client-side index page `http://localhost:3000/` is run or refreshed, it generates an error on the server-side.

On the client-side I have the following component which is fetching data from the back-end:

```
class App extends Component {
state = {
    data: null,
    loading: true,
    error: false
  };

    componentDidMount() {
    // Pick whatever host/port your server is listening on
    fetch('http://localhost:5000/getData')
      .then(res => { // <-- The `results` response object from your backend
        // fetch handles errors a little unusually
        if (!res.ok) {
          throw res;
        }
        // Convert serialized response into json
        return res.json()
      }).then(data => {
        // setState triggers re-render
        this.setState({loading: false, data});
      }).catch(err => {
        // Handle any errors
        console.error(err);
        this.setState({loading: false, error: true});
      });
  }
```

on the server-side, I have the following route:

```
router.get('/getData', function(req, res) {
    var token = req.query.token;
request('https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts?access_token=' + token,  function (error, response, body) {
    if(error){
      console.log(error);
    }else{
          let views = []
   JSON.parse(body).items.forEach(view => {
            views.push({
              name: view.webPropertyId + ' - ' + view.name + ' (' + view.websiteUrl + ')'
            })
          })
      console.log(views)
      res.send(views);

    }
});
})
```

Here is the error I have `TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined` about this line of code `JSON.parse(body).items.forEach(view => {`

My understanding is that the `componentDidMount()` component is fetching the back-end before I'm able to properly authenticate. No authentication, no token, server-side request against the Google Analytics response is empty and `forEach` is undefined.

What should I do to avoid this error?

Comment: One of the possible hack is to wrap your forEach in a condition, `if(JSON.parse(body)){  //Your forEach loop }`.

Comment: It could work but I was thinking about something else. Another solution. Something about the way I should architecture my app if it makes sense.